# How can I free a malloc'd attribute of a stack-allocated struct?

Tags: c, struct, malloc, free

```
typedef struct {
int s;
...
char* temp_status;
...
} param;

pararm MQK;
MQK.temp_status = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*14); 

...

free(&(MQK.temp_status));    <<< ERROR
```

**Error report**

```
gcc ...
csim.c: In function ‘main’:
csim.c:348:9: error: attempt to free a non-heap object ‘MQK’ [-  Werror=free-nonheap-object]
 free(&(MQK.temp_status));
     ^
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
```

How should I free it? I have to `free()` a `malloc()`'d attribute of a stack-allocated struct.

Comment: Free the pointer, not its address.  I.e., remove the `&`.   You want to free the same pointer returned my `malloc`, not the address of a variable that contains that pointer.

Comment: IS YOUR CAPS LOCK KEY BROKEN?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MQK.temp_status is a char pointer. You malloc for it , and you can free it

```
free(MQK.temp_status);
```

should me right.

Each pointer have an address. And you cannot free that address `&MQK.temp_status`